# How Edit and Save TextField Data From UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Everyone i'm doing iPhone Project in swift 3. There is one challenging thing for me. I want to make Repeated View With Editable TextFields. Like This Image [image: enter Editable textfields]
I think UITableView is best for this but how can i edit textFields Data and Save Data in same array from where i'm populating when i pressed on save Button.

Actually i want to update Data in coreData when user change anything from textFields Data. Any solution for save Data or If you have any other solution other than UITableView please guide me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: UITableView is a bit to overpowered in this use-case, I would use a UIScrollView instead. CoreData is a good idea. There are many tutorials out there where you can learn about UITextField, CoreData and UIScrollView.

Comment: Thanks Fabio for quick reply.. so how can i repeat same UIView 10 to 12 times on Scroll View?

Comment: @FabioBerger I disagree. If you are planning to include more fields and want to reuse them in an easy manner, `UITableView` might be the better solution.

Comment: Yes the4man i agrre with you thats why i'm using UITableView. But i'm stuck on save TextFields Data

Comment: In your `cellForRow` method, set the tag of your save button to `indexPath.row` and delete button to `-indexPath.row`. On button press, just look at the `abs(sender.tag)` and that will be the index in your array that needs to be updated or deleted

Comment: @the4kman Well I was thinking to make a view subclass for each record and put them in scroll view. Adding other fields wouldn't be a problem. I assumed it would only have a few recordings so the benefit of cell recycling would be minimal.

Comment: @Malik right but how can i get TextFields Edited Data in SaveButton TargetMethods?

Comment: You won't. You'll need to use a similar approach with your textFields i.e. give them a tag. Then make your viewcontroller implement Text Field Delegate. Implement the `didChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method of the textfield. This method will be called anytime a textfield is edited. Look at the tag and update the information in the array that contains your data.

Comment: what about this Approch?
func targetFuncForSavebutton(sender : UIButton) -> String?{
        
        var value : String?
        let index = sender.tag
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        guard let cell = self.viewController.vitalsTableVu.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? VitalsCell else{
            return nil
        }
        
        if let text = cell.vitalsLabel.text, !text.isEmpty {
            value = text
        }
        
        return value
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array containing the text written in textfield. Firstly, Initiate array with capacity of number of cell and add empty string to each index.

Then, as an when you write in any textfield in textFieldDidEndEditing save that text to array at proper index by getting cell index from point (textfield).

In cellForRow just assign the values of array according to indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

I have Done with this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddVitalCell") as! AddVitalCell
    cell.saveBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.saveBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(targetFuncForSavebutton(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func targetFuncForSavebutton(_ sender : UIButton){

    var value : String?
    let index = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    guard let cell = self.viewController.vitalsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AddVitalCell else{
        return
    }

    if let text = cell.testTxt.text, !text.isEmpty {
        value = text
        print("Geting Value \(value)")
    }

}
```

Thanks All For Response